# Creating DOM 'option' elements with 'selected' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this code would work fine in jQuery 1.5 and not in jQuery 1.6? Was there a known change to how jquery creates DOM nodes between these two versions?

```
var birth = new Date(),
    current = new Date().getFullYear() - 13,
    year = $('select#year'),
    i = 0;
birth.setFullYear(1992, 10, 3);
while (i < 48) {
    var option = $('<option>', { 
        value: current - i,
        text: current - i,
        selected: (current - i === birth.getFullYear()) ? 'selected' : ''
    });
    year.append(option);
    i++;
}
```

See [this working jsfiddle using 1.5](http://jsfiddle.net/tauren/Z7umc/2/) and [this non-working jsfiddle using 1.6](http://jsfiddle.net/tauren/Z7umc/1/). The first only selects one option, but the second adds `selected="selected"` to every option.

Note I've only tested this in Chrome at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
selected: (current - i === birth.getFullYear()) ? 'selected' : ''
```

will generate either

```
selected="selected"
```

or

```
selected=""
```

In both of these cases, the browser considers `selected` set. That's because `selected` is a Boolean; Its mere presence signals that it should be selected.

You should use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), which was introduced in jQuery 1.6:

```
var option = $('<option>', { 
        value: current - i,
        text: current - i
    }).prop('selected', current - i === birth.getFullYear());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7umc/3/

Or, if you prefer to have it all within your object:

```
var option = $('<option>', { 
        value: current - i,
        text: current - i,
        selected: (current - i === birth.getFullYear())
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there a good reason to use the first solution that uses `prop` over your second solution that just returns a boolean in the object?

Comment: @Tauren: Nope. They're both identical. I just put it there because you wanted to know what's changed between 1.5 to 1.6. In 1.6, jQuery started handling Boolean values as, well, Booleans. So you can't set it to an empty string anymore.

Answer (score 0):

set the else part to false

```
var birth = new Date(),
    current = new Date().getFullYear() - 13,
    year = $('select#year'),
    i = 0;
birth.setFullYear(1992, 10, 3);
while (i < 48) {
    var option = $('<option>', {
        value: current - i,
        text: current - i,
        selected: ((current - i) === (birth.getFullYear())) ? 'selected' :false
    });
    year.append(option);
    i++;
}
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z7umc/4/